# Failed at the appium-chromedriver@4.0.0 install script

Tags: installation, appium, ubuntu-16.04

I am getting the below error when I am running "**sudo npm install -g appium**" on ubuntu-16.04

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! appium-chromedriver@4.0.0 install: `node install-npm.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the appium-chromedriver@4.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/anjan-349/.npm/_logs/2018-06-04T09_55_11_739Z-debug.log
```

If you know please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "sudo npm install -g appium --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root" This command install the appium correctly. but not working when I type "appium" in terminal. It says: "appium: command not found"

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**sudo npm install -g appium --unsafe-perm=true**

You will not be able to use appium in the same terminal, you will encounter an error "command not found". So close the current terminal and open a new one.

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo npm install -g appium --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

This helped in my case and I was able to run Appium in the same terminal right after the installation completed.